# where team members are out of scope of a step should they be excluded or listed with 'no action required' message?

Tags: intuition, actions

Managers need to complete certain activities throughout the year for their team members.  In some circumstances managers do not need to complete any activities for a member of their team (e.g. the team member may be new to the business and isn't eligible for performance appraisal).

Should the page where a line manager goes to view their 'team actions required' display all team members with the relevant action required stated (i.e. do something or do nothing), or should the page only display the team members where action is required.

I think it should show all, if it doesn't the manager may think there is an error with the data and not aware of the ineligibility.  However, the ineligibility reasons vary so much that we not be able to configure the system to automatically populate the specific reason why the team member is not eligible so it may simply state 'team member jo bloggs is not eligible for performance appraisal'

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts, experience, and knowledge.

This is what the OOTB solution looks like, Aruna and Jane are not eligible for performance assessment so don't have any 'action' for the line manager to complete.  I am hoping the system can enter the 'ineligibility reason' in the grey box, however some have suggested not have the team members displayed here if no action is required.
[image: mock up of line manager performance actions for their team]

Comment: The workflow you describe is pretty clear, but it would be helpful if you included a sketch, wireframe or screenshot to illustrate the two interfaces you're considering.

Comment: Thanks - I have added a very draft image of the out of the box solution that I'm seeking advice on.

Comment: that's helpful, thanks. One more question: is this the primary team-management view, or is this a specialized view (e.g. only for required actions) and there is another primary view or home page that managers use which contains the team overview including all the members?

Comment: There are multiple screens for a manager to view in the system at different stages throughout the year.  At the time that managers need to go in and action this step, this is the primary page they need to go to and will be directed straight to this page.  This not a team management view as the manage their team and team data in another system altogether.  My concern is if they don't see all their team they may call our help desk to find out why the person is not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess your goals for the page are:

1. Clearly present the manager with what to do.  That means: (a) which team members need to be actioned; and (b) what action needs to be done.
2. Give the manager assurance that other team members are not being forgotten/ignored/left out unintentionally.

Since #1 is more important than #2, the layout should be focused primarily on #1, but also provide #2 as a secondary goal.

Here is an example approach:

[image: team]

This presents the manager with a clear view of the team members who need actions.
Below the action panel, there is a clear header which acknowledges that there are 12 other team members who do not have any actions.
The details of the 12 are not shown initially, so as to reduce clutter on screen and retain focus on the action panel.  But if the manager is curious, she can click to expand and make sure the other team members have not been ignored by the system.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ps forgive the bad pronoun in the wireframe

Comment: Thanks - such a logical and simple response, its interesting when you get so stuck in a system how hard it is to step 'out of the system' and see it from an end user perspective.  Thanks.

Comment: Totally agree on the tunnel vision...outside perspective is one of the roles UX.SE plays well. Good luck!